# What is the best way to sync two mongodb server without master server?

Tags: mongodb, database-mirroring

There is a production server for realtime data collection in remote server room. My workshop also have a server for offline data analytics. Is there any way to sync those 2 database without a master? It looks like master-slave needs master accessible even I connect to the slave.
I know I can run mongodump and mongorestore, but the data is too big to carry through network. I need some way could do incremental updating and works like mirroring.

Thanks.

Comment: You can potentially do some incremental dumps of new data using the [`--query`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--query) flag for `mongodump`. Are you only planning on doing reads for your local MongoDB server, or do you need to write to that as well?

Comment: @Stennie I will need to write analytics results(not the same documents as source) to another database but the same server. Query is not a good option because not all documents contains field for incremental query.